# jquery invoke JS method in context

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are using `jQuery` in our application for making AJAX calls. How do I inovke a method in a particular context using `jQuery`? In `dojo` we used to do it using `dojo.hitch()`.
Is there something similar in jQuery? Below is the sample code that we are using. I need to execute the `success` handler in the context of `SampleMethod`. The below code should
give me exception since `resultSetHandler` is not available in the window context. Could you please let me know.

We are using `jQuery` version **1.3.2**

```
function SampleMethod(){
    this.invokeProcedure=function(procedurePath){
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: procedurePath,
                dataType: "json",
                success: resultSetHandler,
                error: errorHandler
            });
    }

    this.resultSetHandler=function(args){
        //Handle the result
    }

    this.errorHandler=function(args){
        //Handle the result
    }

}

var sampleObj=new SampleMethod();
sampleObj.invokeProcedure('url');
```

Comment: jQuery 1.3.2 was released on 2009-02-19 -- That makes it 3.5 years old, which is an eternity in the jQuery release cycle.  I definitely suggest updating to at LEAST 1.5 to get the new ajax rewrite code, but you might as well jump up to the latest (1.7) or even try out 1.8 beta, as it is soon to be released.

Comment: In particular note that 1.3.2 predates the release of IE9.

Comment: Also the 1059 fixed bugs since 1.3.2: http://bit.ly/MfB9hv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just preserve `this` and wrap them in functions:

```
this.invokeProcedure=function(procedurePath){
        var savedThis = this;
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: procedurePath,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function() { savedThis.resultSetHandler(); },
                error: function() { savedThis.errorHandler(); }
            });
    }
```

(Probably should pass the "success" function argument forward to "resultSetHandler" too.)

---

*edit* — the above will handle this sort of issue in the general case, but @Blaster correctly points out in a comment that the jQuery `$.ajax` mechanism provides a simpler solution. A `context` property can be set in the parameter object you pass in, and the value will be used as the context for the callbacks. That is, adding:

```
context: this,
```

to the `$.ajax` parameter object would make things work as you originally wrote it.

Comment: @Blaster well it's a matter of taste :-)  Sometimes a name that evokes the nature of the object is good, but in this case I couldn't think  of anything clever.

Comment: @Pointry: I suspect `context: this` should also do the trick there instead of that.

Comment: @Blaster oh dang you're right; I always forget that on these questions. I'll add it.

Comment: `context: this` ajax option also is not available until jQuery 1.4+ http://jsfiddle.net/FAVar/ <-- 1.3 here

Comment: @gnarf ah thanks that makes me feel better for forgetting about it :-)

Comment: @Blaster On jQuery UI project we basically outlawed `var self = this;` in favor of `that`, and in recent releases, in favor of `proxy`ied methods.   The `self` can cause an issue if you forget to define it because there is a `window.self` - and `that` just gets annoying to look at after a while.  Proxied methods really are the most efficient way to handle this problem MOST of the time, and it doesn't introduce a var into a scope that you rely on anymore either.  It allows you to define your functions outside of that scope as well, yet still carry the proper context.

Comment: @gnarf: Hmm makes sense, thanks for useful information, I loved your proxy solution as well which is why had already +1ed you too :)

Answer (score 2):

That version of jQuery is hopelessly old at this point, you should upgrade.  The function you are looking for is [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) and is only available in 1.4+

If you are upgrading though you should consider upgrading to latest, you're only 4 major versions behind right now.

If you are working in an environment which won't allow you to upgrade 3.5 year old libraries, consider copying the [source of `jQuery.proxy`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/8f01b92b8fd85a66f2cba671f8b9ff6f7095c34b/src/core.js#L738-765) for yourself and making it work.

Comment: I had seen this. But unfortunately we can't use it since our version is 1.3.2.

Comment: @Apps - There is no good excuse in 2012 to not upgrade beyond 1.3.2.